# git - can't merge branch into master, conflicting files

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have a file called index.html in master branch. I create dev branch and switch into the dev branch

```
git branch dev
git checkout dev
```

I then edit index.html and commit the change

```
git commit -m "first change" index.html
```

I am still in the dev branch. Now I want master to have this new feature so I try to merge the dev branch into master

```
git merge master
```

but I get

```
Auto-merging index.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in index.html
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

It seems I am stuck, I have to do git merge --abort but how can I ever do the merge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: technically, this shouldn't raise any merge conflicts.. did you change the index.html in **master** after you created the branch from master?

Comment: You will face merge conflicts when the same file has been edited in the master branch. Read this https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts to learn how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You are not stuck, git tells you "Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result."

so fix the conflicts and then commit the result...

if you googled it you would have find this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/163659/1346690

Comment: Does this mean every time I wish to merge my dev branch into master I need to use the mergetool? If that is the case aren't I do something wrong with merging? This happens every time I do what I did above.

Comment: no that is weird.

Conflicts can arises when you have a modification on the same file on both branches.
Here you had no change on index.html in the master branch so it's definitly weird.

Comment: what did merge tool showed you? what were the conflicts about?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> git branch dev
> git checkout dev
> ```

Just use one command `git checkout -b dev`.

> Now I want master to have this new feature so I try to merge the dev branch into master
>
> git merge master

To merge `dev` into `master` the proper commands are

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

In case of conflicts resolve them using editor, add resolved files with `git add` and commit.